# Show/ hide elements on page with conditional html selects

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

*This is most likely a duplicate, but I couldn't find snippets that help me out*

I have a page with multiple images and two select fields. I want to show depending on the selection of the user different images. For the individual selects this is easy, but how can I achieve a dependency between both selects the easy way?

**Example:**
Items on Page: "A B", "A", "B"
**User selection:**
First select: A
Second select: B
**Result: "A B"**

**User selection:**
First select: A
Second select: empty
**Result: "A"**

I think you get the point.

The few snippets I've found are made with jQuery and I would really like to avoid jQuery and only use vanilla JS.

My current approach:

```js
let redShown;
let blueShown;
let greenShown;

let oneShown;
let twoShown;
let threeShown;


// ColorFilter
function colorFilter(select) {
  if (select.value == "red") {
    redShown = true;
    blueShown = false;
    greenShown = false;
    // Show Red
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box.red").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box.red")[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
    // Hide everything else than red
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.red)").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.red)")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (select.value == "blue") {
    blueShown = true;
    redShown = false;
    greenShown = false;
    // Show Blue
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box.blue").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box.blue")[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
    // Hide everything else than blue
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.blue)").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.blue)")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (select.value == "green") {
    greenShown = true;
    redShown = false;
    blueShown = false;
    // Show Green
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box.green").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box.green")[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
    // Hide everything else than green
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.green)").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.green)")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}



// Numberfilter
function numberFilter(select) {
  if (select.value == "one") {
    oneShown = true;
    twoShown = false;
    threeShown = false;
    // Show 1 
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box.one").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box.one")[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
    // Hide everything else than 1
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.one)").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.one)")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (select.value == "two") {
    oneShown = false;
    twoShown = true;
    threeShown = false;
    // Show 2
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box.two").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box.two")[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
    // Hide everything else than 2
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.two)").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.two)")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (select.value == "three") {
    oneShown = false;
    twoShown = false;
    threeShown = true;
    // Show 3
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box.three").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box.three")[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
    // Hide everything else than 3
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.three)").length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".box:not(.three)")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 
 .box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 2rem;
   
 }
 
 .box.red {
   background: red;
 }
 
 .box.green {
   background: green;
 }
 
 .box.blue {
   background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<select id="colorSelect" onchange="colorFilter(this)">
  <option disabled selected value="">Color</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="numberSelect" onchange="numberFilter(this)">
  <option disabled selected value="">Number</option>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>


<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="box red one">1</div>
  <div class="box red two">2</div>
  <div class="box red three">3</div>
  <div class="box blue one">1</div>
  <div class="box blue two">2</div>
  <div class="box blue three">3</div>
  <div class="box green one">1</div>
  <div class="box green two">2</div>
  <div class="box green three">3</div>
</div>
```

Right now the selects overwrite each other, so they don't work together.

Also my code is super complex because I write out every possible combination by hand. There has to be a shorter version for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the same event listener to both selects and set display properties of each box depending on the changed values of the number select and color select. PS: I tweaked HTML a little bit so it is easier to access box' variables (added data-color attribute for the color value and data-number attribute for the number value). In addition, I've changed numberSelect values from "one", "two" and "three" to "1", "2" and "3". Also, the code is 100% free of jQuery :-)

See the implementation below:

```js
let colorSelect = document.getElementById('colorSelect');
let numberSelect = document.getElementById('numberSelect');
let boxWrapper = document.getElementById('boxWrapper');

function handleChange() {
  // Get new values for changed color
  // and changed number which user selected
  let changedColor = colorSelect.value;
  let changedNumber = numberSelect.value;
  
  // Get the list of all boxes inside our box wrapper div
  let boxes = boxWrapper.querySelectorAll('.box');
  
  // For each box check whether its display property
  // should be 'block' or 'none' based on changed values
  // in colorSelect and numberSelect
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    // Get color and number values from the current box
    let color = box.getAttribute('data-color');
    let number = box.getAttribute('data-number');
    
    // Check whether current box color and number values
    // comply to user changed values in selects
    let isColorValid = !changedColor || changedColor === color;
    let isNumberValid = !changedNumber || changedNumber === number;
    
    // If both color and number values comply - display the box
    // otherwise hide the box using display: none
    if (isColorValid && isNumberValid) {
        box.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        box.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
}

// Attach listeners to both colorSelect and numberSelect
colorSelect.addEventListener('change', () => handleChange());
numberSelect.addEventListener('change', () => handleChange());
```

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 
 .box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 2rem;
   
 }
 
 .box.red {
   background: red;
 }
 
 .box.green {
   background: green;
 }
 
 .box.blue {
   background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<select id="colorSelect">
  <option disabled selected value="">Color</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="numberSelect">
  <option disabled selected value="">Number</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="flex-wrapper" id="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box red" data-color="red" data-number="1">1</div>
  <div class="box red" data-color="red" data-number="2">2</div>
  <div class="box red" data-color="red" data-number="3">3</div>
  <div class="box blue" data-color="blue" data-number="1">1</div>
  <div class="box blue" data-color="blue" data-number="2">2</div>
  <div class="box blue" data-color="blue" data-number="3">3</div>
  <div class="box green" data-color="green" data-number="1">1</div>
  <div class="box green" data-color="green" data-number="2">2</div>
  <div class="box green" data-color="green" data-number="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also just came across data attributes but didn't made anything with it yet. So far it's working great and I will mark it soon as correct. Just let me test it a bit if I understand everything correctly. Love it how much less code this is in comparison to my (non working) "solution"

Comment: No worries. Whenever you need an HTML element to hold a value always use a data-attribute. They are much more reliable as a source of information instead of something like parsing the element's classes and making choices based on those values.

Comment: I have one question: How does `isColorValid` know which of the `OR` statements it should use?

Comment: It doesn't. It uses both isColorValid and isNumberValid. That is because we've binded the same function (handleChange) to both selects. So whenever a change is detected, the logic of reevaluation color and number is executed. So for a box to be visible it must match with the selected number (only if a number is selected) and match with the selected color (only if a color is selected)